# Symfony 2 collection unique elements constraint, mapping errors to children

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I have a formtype with single field: collection, containing unspecified number of anonymous selects. Is there a way to check if there are duplicate choices using builtin constraints? In case I have to write constraint myself, there is another problem. If I add the constraint on parent, how can I add error to  child on specific index? If I add the constraint on children using All - how can I access values of other children?

Selects are allowed to return null value. The form is not bound to entity.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after digging through 10 pages of Google and SO results, I didn't find anything. So, I dug further, and as often happens, I've found solution in unit tests - [symfony github link to this specific thing which solved my problem](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/bd577b11a253c483092310761746950ce243aa58/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Tests/Constraints/CollectionValidatorTest.php#L90).

Now when I want to add error to specific field in collection, I can do:

```
$this->context->addViolationAt('['.$i.']', 'Error in field %d', $i);
```

This is case for unnamed collection children with default numeric indexes, I didn't test it with named ones. Also - remember about collection having error_bubbling enabled by default.